# Selenium2Library keywords not recognized in PyCharm

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am new to the RobotFramework and wanted to get a simple example up and running on PyCharm. I am not too clear on what exactly I need to run the Robot Framework so I installed Python 2.7, robotframework, selenium and robotframework-selenium2library. I am not sure if I need to install the webdriver or the googlechrome driver as well.

What am I missing so that I can run this example? I am really clueless.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the `chromedriver.exe` and have to keep it in `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder. It will pick up the `exe` from there and run your code.

and follow [link](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/10/11/configuring-pycharm-to-run-tests.html)